# Sequence of UML diagrams

Tags: uml, use-case, sequence-diagram

What are the sequence that i need to follow when creating UML diagrams

Can you number it and show it as mandatory?

In my thought its should be like below:

1. Use Case       (mandatory)
2. Sequence       (mandatory)
3. Activity
4. state
5. Collaboration
6. Class          (mandatory)

Please correct if i m wrong !

Comment: All of these are optional. Personally, I don't care much about UML.  I don't think they're required to write software well.

Comment: @duffymo, they are not required to write software well, though they are a way of describing the software design and model, which in many cases helps different actors in the software development process to understand it better and in an easier way.

Comment: I know what UML is, thank you. This question is 10 years old.  Use your time here more productively.

Answer (score 4):

In the general sense there is no sequence you "need" to follow and no diagram is mandatory.

There are UML-centric methodologies (e.g. RUP, FDD, ICONIX as mentioned elsewhere) that prescibe an ordering and which diagrams should be produced.

So the answer to your question as written is:

- If you're using a specific methodology - **and** sticking rigorously to it - then it will tell you what to produce when.
- Otherwise there is none.

If you're trying to adopt a UML-based development approach then I'd suggest you look at the various methodologies and decide which to use - which will answer your question.

**However.**  Overriding all of that: UML is a set of tools.  Use them as and when useful, and don't be a slave to process for process' sake.

hth.

Comment: I agree very much with this answer and thus it has my "thumbs up", except with its last "However" conclusion. Different methodologies evolved because of a reason and all those different reasons might be the reason why you would prefer one or another sequence of creating those diagrams. So my advice - knowing your methodologies and understanding UML will help you find your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use case diagram, Class diagram, Object diagram, State diagram, Sequence diagram, Collaboration diagram, Activity diagram, Deployment diagram, Component diagram

for reference use below link

http://www.globalshiksha.com/What-is-the-sequence-of-UML-diagrams-in-project-/ugc/4151036607101480

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing  like "*UML-based development approach* ".

UML is just a notation. It is not a "process" which guide you:

```
Role ---> Activity ---> Artifact
```

If you want such a guide you can look Rational Unified Process. Or more light weigt open version OpenUP
http://www.eclipse.org/epf/downloads/configurations/pubconfig_downloads.php can be downloaded

[image]

**But none of the software process are "like" go and buy clothes.** All process  should be tailored for your project specific needs. Otherwise "process" will just kill your software project.**Sfinnie
is absolutely right**.

In his book Larman(Applying UML and Patterns: An Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis and Design and Iterative Development)  apply Rup with Uml  in a light weight way.

Here is a short decription of his way of using Uml (http://www.objectsbydesign.com/books/larman_process.html)

[image]

**Be carefull DO NOT DEAD BY UML FEVER**!!! 
[Death by UML Fever](http://0-queue.acm.org.millennium.lib.cyut.edu.tw/detail.cfm?id=984495)

Answer (score 0):

Your ordering looks about right, bu I'm not sure if there is a mandatory sequence for creating UML diagrams for a project. You should really be able to dip in an out of UML when it suits you.

If you want to put a structure on how you use UML, you should have a look into the various software modelling processes that are out there. One that I have used quite a bit is the ICONIX process, http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=167902. This is a light weight process based on use cases.

Answer (score -3):

In IT projects we create so-call project diagrams based on UML diagrams. In the majority of projects using UML diagrams (Choi, H., Yeom, K.: An Approach to Software Architecture Evaluation with the 4+1 View Model of Architecture. In: Ninth Asia-Pacific Software Engineering Conference, pp. 286—293. IEEE Computer Society, 2002), (Kennaley M.: The 3+1 Views of Architecture (in 3D): An Amplification of the 4+1 View-point Framework. In Seventh Working IEEE/IFIP Conference, pp. 299—302. IEEE Com-puter Society, 2008), use case diagrams are developed at the beginning of software development to describe the main functions of the software-based system. Then class diagrams are created to show the structure of the system, and state machine diagrams are built to show the behaviour of system’s elements (Issa A., Abu Rub F.A.: Performing Early Feasibility Studies of Software Development Projects Using Business Process Models, Proceedings of the World Congress on Engineer-ing 2007 Vol I WCE 2007, July 2 - 4, 2007, London, U.K.), (Dijkman R.M., Joosten S.M.: An Algorithm to Derive Use Case Diagrams from Business Process Models, 6th International Conference on Software Engineering and Applications (SEA), Anaheim, CA, USA, Acta Press, pp. 679-684, 2002). Subsequently activity or sequence diagram can be used in order to verify consistency of other diagrams. These diagrams are also using visualizing scenarios i.e. – use case realization diagrams.
But in my UML projects first I create context diagram based on activity UML diagram. Context diagram contains one main process, a few events on input, and a few products or services on output.
Then I create decomposition diagram, which next enable to build busioness use case diagram. 
Now, for each use case, I first prepare use case realisation diagram based on activity diagram. 
From each use case realisation diagram I derive: class, state, and system uses case diagrams.
Next I may create a sequence diagram based on the system use case diagram to show intrnal behaviour and structure of IT system. In the end I create component diagram (based on the sequence diagram), and deployment diagram (based on the component diagram).
Stanisław Jerzy Niepostyn, project-media.pl

Comment: Please format your answer and make it more readable.